# C# Parse Memory Stream text from RichTextBox with special characters

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf, text-parsing

I need your help to find the best/fastest way to parse *(regular expression)* text in a RichTextbox.

I have already tried several methods, and the fastest one, so far, seems to be saving the text into a MemoryStream and read it line by line while performing the validation.

I have no problem doing that and it actually seems to work pretty well... Except, when I have special chars - Latin chars to be more specific. Lets say for example that I have the name, "***João***" (John in English BTW), the text, coming from the StreamReader, appears as ***"Jo\'e3o"***... resulting in a failure to find the text.

Not sure if this is because of encoding, I have tried to set the Encoding to UTF8 when creating the StreamReader, but it doesn't work, I always see the text with those codes.

I am starting to think that my only option is to parse the text or lines from the RichTextbox obj, but it is sooooo much slower...

***UPDATE***

Adding some example code on how I'm reading the RichTextBox text.
*(This seems to be the fastest way to read large amounts of text.)*

```
var rtb = new RichTextBox();
var rtbMemStream = new MemoryStream();
rtb.SaveFile(rtbMemStream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rtbStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var streamLine = sr.ReadLine();
        ParseLine(streamLine);
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated,

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I'd suggest including some code we can test it, and tagging with the appropriate platform (WinForms or WPF)

Comment: Where does the memory stream fit into this? You should be able to just read the text as a string, and "João" is like any other. NET string

Comment: @KeithStein Thnks or replying. Just added some code. cheers

Comment: @Flydog57 I've added some example code. If one has a couple of lines to parse, using the text property works pretty well. But when you are dealing with large amounts of text, saving the text into a memory stream seems to be a lot faster. tnks

Comment: Are you interested in the text only? If so, you shouldn't save using `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` because this would include RTF markup and escaping.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis unfortunately I need to preserve already applied styles... This is for highlighting several pieces of text that match a criteria. But actually that got me thinking if I could save the match index parsing the plaintext and afterwards set the highlight... Great tip, I'll take a look 

Comment: @Nuno accidental tip :) but glad you found a potential solution!